# algorithm - Coin change in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

I have seen quite many coin change problems and this one is quite unique. I tried using DP and recursion but I wasn't able to solve it.

This is the problem:

Let's say given a price, X, where X is in cents and I have 5 finite coin denominations, 1,5,10,20,50. I have different number of 1,5,10,20,50-cent coins. I want to make price X with the maximum number of coins. How do I do it?(Assuming X can always be made with the coins at hand)

For example, if price X = 52 and

i have 3 of 1-cent coins

I have 4 of 5-cent coins

I have 8 of 10-cent coins

I have 6 of 20-cent coins

I have 4 of 50-cent coins

I want to find the maximum number of coins and number of ways that can be used to make this price, in this case: two 1-cent, four 5-cent, 3 10-cent coins will be the answer.

I have thought of a usable algorithm where first, I put the number and value of each coin into an arraylist, then I pass the array list into a recursive function that will:

First, deduct the price with the smallest denomination, then add 1 to int max, where max = number of coins currently used. Then, recursively call the function with price=price-smallest denomination.

Second, I'll recursively call the function by taking the next smallest available denomination.

My base cases are that if

```
1) price <0, return 0

2) if price ==0 and max=currMax,  return 1

3) if price>0, recursively call the 2 recursions listed above
```

EDIT: to add in code.

I modified the question a little bit.

```
  1 import java.util.*;
  2 public class CountingChange{
  3     int max = 0; //maximum number of way to pay price
  4     int way = 0; //number of ways to make price
  5     private void run(){
  6         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  7         int price = sc.nextInt();
  8         ArrayList<Integer> coins = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //kinds of coins. assumed to be 1,5,10,20,50
  9         for (int i = 0; i <5; i++){
 10             int coin = sc.nextInt();
 11             coins.add(i,coin);
 12         }
 13         int currMax = 0;
 14         counter(price,coins,currMax);
 15         System.out.println(String.valueOf(max) + " " + String.valueOf(way)); //output eg: 10 5, where 10 = max coins, 5 = ways
 16     }
 17     private void counter(int price,ArrayList<Integer> coins,int currMax){
 18         currMax += 1;
 19         if (coins.size()==0) return;             
              else if((coins.get(0)<0)||(price<0)){
 20             //check if AL is empty(no way to make change), smallest coin < 0(invalid), price<0(invalid)
 21             return;
 22         }
 23         else if (price==0){//successful change made
 24             if (currMax==max){ //check max coins used
 25                 way+=1;
 26             }
 27             else if (currMax>max){
 28                 way = 1;
 29                 max = currMax;
 30             }
 31         }
 32         else if(price>0){
 33             coins.set(0,coins.get(0)-1);//use smallest coin
 34             counter(price-coins.get(0),coins,currMax);
 35             coins.remove(0);//use other coins except smallest
 36             counter(price,coins,currMax);
 37         }
 38     }
 39     public static void main(String[] args){
 40         CountingChange myCountingChange = new CountingChange();
 41         myCountingChange.run();
 42     }
 43 }
```

I believe my problem is that I was deducting the number of coins(instead of the value of coin) used to make the price. But I really have no idea how to use a suitable//what kind of data structure to store my coins and its value.

Comment: "what kind of data structure to store my coins" : a Purse ? Joke aside, please show what you have tried so far .

Comment: All pennies will always be the max number of coins to get x.

Comment: Have you considered using backtracking to find all solutions and simply selecting the one with the most coins in it?

Comment: @Berger edited code in

Comment: @Sedrick Jefferson Ahh, not true. I have finite number of pennies.

Comment: @RobObdeijn I tried but the problem now is that I can't seem to think of a proper way to store  the coins. I have been deducting wrongly from the number of coins rather than the value of coins for the price.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part in the description.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you do want the maximum number of coins right? you can simple use a `List<List<Integer>>` that contains all solutions where the solution with the maximum number of coins is the inner list with the most elements and the number of ways is the size of the outer list.

Comment: I doubt "two 1-cent, four 5-cent, 3 10-cent coins" will be the only answer, I think there will be multiple answer to achieve maximum price 52.

Comment: I was able to solve your problem using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to keep track of which coins have been added at each point in the recursion. Use a 2nd list to keep track of the current maximum solution. When you find a solution check if it has more coins than the current max.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50 };
    int[] available = { 3, 4, 8, 6, 4 };
    int change = 52;
    List<Integer> maxCoins = new ArrayList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> coins = new LinkedList<>();

    maxCoins(0, change, values, available, maxCoins, coins);

    System.out.println(maxCoins);
}

public static void maxCoins(int pos, int change, int[] values, int[] available, List<Integer> maxCoins, LinkedList<Integer> coins)
{
    if (change == 0)
    {
        if (maxCoins.isEmpty() || maxCoins.size() < coins.size())
        {
            maxCoins.clear();
            maxCoins.addAll(coins);
        }
    } 
    else if (change < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = pos; i < values.length && values[i] <= change; i++)
    {
        if (available[i] > 0)
        {
            available[i]--;
            coins.addLast(values[i]);
            maxCoins(i, change - values[i], values, available, maxCoins, coins);
            coins.removeLast();
            available[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10]
```